# Intellij spring boot app does not work from tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, spring-boot

This is my class

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class TomcatIcınApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TomcatIcınApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/hi")
    String hello( ) {
        return "Hello, xx!";
    }
}
```

When i run application and open `localhost:8080/hello/hi`, i can see the output. But from `Edit Configurations`, when i add tomcat server on port `8081` as `localhost:8081/hello` and run tomcat this time, it invokes app and opens page but it is empty.

Why can't i see my output?

Comment: I think you need to visit this url- http://localhost:8081/ProjectName/hello/hi where project name is the war file name that you deploy in Tomcat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you simply run the application, Spring Boot will use its embedded tomcat server to run your application. If you're planning to use another standalone tomcat server to deploy your boot application, *which i do not recommend*, first you should tell your build tool to package your application as a `war` not `jar`. Then modify your main boot application entry point to support that and finally deploy your `war` file to your tomcat server either by using Intellij or manually.

The first step in producing a deployable war file is to provide a `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass and override its `configure` method. In you case:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TomcatIcınApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TomcatIcınApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TomcatIcınApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then tell your build tool to package your application as a `war`, not `jar`. If you're using maven, simply add:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

And finally mark the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as `provided`:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

You read more about spring boot *Traditional deployment* [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#howto-traditional-deployment).

Comment: I changed jar to war and i added dependency you wrote because i dont have such artifactid. And in edit configurations, when i add tomcat server, it says no artifact. should i create a web archive explored file as artifact?

Comment: yes i added, i put all available elements to left and now when i go to http://localhost:8081/hello/hi it works. Thank you.

Comment: If i just run the app in IntelliJ it does not start tomcat, only if I start using  maven `spring-boot:run`. Removed `provided` started as expected.

Comment: Why it is not recommended to run a Spring Boot app in a standalone tomcat server?